# Javascript Date format not working with GetDay

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I am using a jquery datepicker and i had an option box being populated with info depending on what day it was..

Worked perfectly...

```js
$('#bydate').datepicker({
    showOn: "button",
    buttonImage: "images/calendar.gif",
    buttonImageOnly: true,
    beforeShowDay: unavailable,
    minDate: -0,
    dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
    onSelect: function(e) {
    var date = new Date(e);
    var day = date.getDay(); // 0 = sunday etc...        
    // clean all the options
    $("#duration").empty();
    // if monday
    if (day === 1) {
        // add "5 days" options
        $("#duration").append("<option value='5'>5 days</option>");
    // else if friday
    } else if (day === 5) {
        // add 3 / 7 / 14 days options
        $("#duration").append("<option value='3'>3 days</option>"
                              + "<option value='7'>7 days</option>"
                              + "<option value='14'>14 days</option>");
    } else { // else...
    }
}
```

Until i came to needing to change the format from mm/dd/yy to dd/mm/yy.

Now it doesn't work, it looks like getDay is getting the month number and trying to calculate the day number...

I need date to know its dd/mm/yy or getDay to know that I am using dd/mm/yy

example here http://offline.raileisure.com/

Comment: I could not understand what is failing? could you add more detail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you changed the format of how the datepicker shows the dates, but not the one of the constructor Date(). You can do this:

```
onSelect: function(e) {
e = e.split('/')[1] + '/' + e.split('/')[0] + '/' + e.split('/')[2];
var date = new Date(e);
...
```

Comment: Thank god, can you believe that stupid little mistake has cost me an hour :-(

Comment: It happens to me at least once a week xD

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the datepicker's parseDate function, which takes the date format as parameter. See http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker/parseDate for details